# Does motherboard limit maximal RAM?

Tags: laptop, memory-limit

I know, there are many questions and answears around this, but I didn't find any to answear my question directly. If we do not care about CPU (Imagine a 64bit one if you are a detailist) or OS or just anything that has something to do with that. Recently I upgraded to 8GB ram, but I find it to be not enough for me at all. Website of the producer of my laptop says, that 8GB of ram is the limit, but the installed CPU says 16GB, so I was confused, now I use a CPU with 32GB max, so I have to ask this. Can motherboard (or BIOS) limit max amount of my ram? I want to upgrade and I'm a poor kid so do not tell me to test as few guys told me

Btw one guy said that he has 8GB limit too and has 16GB and runs without problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manufacturer sets the limit (CPU, BIOS, number of slots and type of memory) and says this is the maximum amount of memory. The vendor's documentation will tell you this and it varies by vendor, make and model of computer. There is no "one" statement about it.

Comment: I would like to ask. My laptop is 2012 or 13 idk, but I think that back to then there was no DDR3 So-Dimm with 8GB so here is the problem. And yeah, how do I find my vendor, Im new in this

Comment: There should be a manufacturer's label on the bottom (or possibly the face) of the machine and then go to their website.

Comment: thanks for help, but I scrolled google lil bit more and one website tested for that and they say that my laptop series support up to 16GB, really thanks anyway